# How can i put some information from a device to another device based on a parity condition?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have to solve a problem at work in pandas where i have a .csv file where i have some information like this:

Element      --- Ticket
**1-X121***1*  --- TT0045
**1-X121***2*

I have 2 elements that form a pair based on 2 conditions:

1. The first 6 characters have to be the same for both of the elements in the pair.
2. The last number forms a pair like this 1 with 2, 3 with 4,  5&6, 7&8, 9&0.
   In this case you can see the pair: 1-X1211 pair with 1-X1212.

What i need to do is to associate the ticket from an element of the pair to the other element in the pair (if a ticket exists in the first place). So in this case to copy the ticket from 1-X1211 -> TT0045 and put it on the other element of the pair 1-X1212. Final it should look like this:

Element

1-X1211 --- TT0045

1-X1212 --- TT0045

I can't share a code because i don't know how to do it.

Thank you,
Iulia

Comment: What you want is unclear. First, update your post with data as plain text (not image) and give the expected output for your sample. It's better if you show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I just edited and i hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['1-x1211', '1-x1212'], 'Ticket': ['TT0045', '']})
print(df)

# Output
        ID  Ticket
0  1-x1211  TT0045
1  1-x1212
```

Create a mapping dict:

```
# 1 -> 2, 3 -> 4, ..., 9 -> 0
odd_to_even = {'1': '2', '3': '4', '5': '6', '7': '8', '9': '0'}

# Extract last char of the ID and replace it by 2, 4, 6, 8 or 0
even_id = df['ID'].astype(str).str[:-1] + df['ID'].astype(str).str[-1].replace(odd_to_even)

# Now find the right ticket for pairwise ID
df['Ticket'] = df.replace('', np.nan).groupby(even_id)['Ticket'].transform('first')
print(df)

# Output
        ID  Ticket
0  1-x1211  TT0045
1  1-x1212  TT0045
```

Comment: I think it's what you expect. Let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! It worked perfectly. :D

Comment: I just accepted the answer (sorry for the delay, i'm new to the platform). Thank you again for your help!